# Microsoft SQL CASE statement in where clause using LIKE

Tags: sql

I once used a scenario where I did a SQL where clause like this: 
where
   BranchName = CASE WHEN @pBranch <> '' then @pBranch else BranchName end

this is to say we're doing a branch name lookup, but this statement has to cater for the LIKE clause somehow. We need to be able to say 'If the pBranch parameter was provided then do a like search else ignore that part of the WHERE clause.

Any clues?

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually I think the answer I was looking for is as follows:

...
where
 o.BranchName like case when  @pBranchName <> '' then @pBranchName  else o.BranchName end
...

Comment: I think that should do the exact same thing as what I posted above, because if you pass in '' then you return everything, otherwise you filter by your @pBranchName

Answer (score 1):

you could say:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo
WHERE @pBranch = '' OR BranchName = @pBranch
```

This basically says that if you pass in '' to @pBranch, then all results will be displayed, otherwise, if you pass in something else, it will search by your argument

Comment: oops - didn't see your post when I made mine. But this is my idea of the right answer!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Where BranchName Like IsNull(@Branch, BranchName)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
where @pBranch = '' or BranchName like @pBranch
```

(add the wildcards to the appropriate spot in the like clause)

this will work for numbers, not just strings - so if you passed in an int parameter as a 0 or a value, you would do:

```
where @param = 0 or DBField = @param
```